# Would like some input on the best indexing for a MongoDB collection for the case below

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection set of objects with 4 ids on them, something like:

```
{ 
    location_id : ObjectId,
    project_id : ObjectId,
    department_id : ObjectId,
    element_id : ObjectId
}
```

I have a specialized endpoint in my data service that takes in an array of these objects, and must return all objects in the collection where the ids match, but nulls in the database are always a match.

Not a difficult query by my book, but what i'm most concerned about is the performance.   If I simply index all 4 ids, is mongo smart enough to handle a query on all 4 efficiently? There could be hundreds of millions of records in this collection and hundreds in the passed-in set to query with.  Is there a more efficient way with secondary indices or is just indexing on all 4 enough for mongo's engine to work it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing all 4 should be enough, but you have a few options depending on the typical queries types your system will perform.

If your queries always search for all 4 fields at the same query, then the all-in index will be enough.

Now, if you have combinations between the fields, then you can have extra indexes tailored to each query, like:

```
db.collection.find({ location_id : ObjectId, project_id : ObjectId });
//index: { location_id : 1, project_id : 1 }

db.collection.find({ location_id : ObjectId, department_id : ObjectId });
//index: { location_id : 1, department_id : 1 }

db.collection.find({ project_id : ObjectId, element_id : ObjectId });
//index: { project_id : 1, element_id : 1 }

...
```

Under the hood, MongoDB will test each possible index on the first few queries and decide which has the better performance for that specific query.

What I usually do is turn the [MongoDB database profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) to log queries slower than 100ms, and then create necessaries indices for each case.

To activate the profiler, run at mongo shell:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(
  1, //0-turn off profiler; 1-log only slow than slowms; 2-log all operations
  { slowms: 100 } //slow than 100ms
);
```

And then check the slower queries:

```
db.system.profile.find().sort({millis:-1}).limit(10).pretty();
```